# CodeIgniter configuration Issue: POST method is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I copied a perfectly working CodeIgniter Project from my friend's computer. Everything else works perfectly fine but none of the forms works. Again I tried sending the form using the GET method and it perfectly works but only the POST method does not work.

This is what the view looks like:

```
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>team/administrator/team/insert" method="post"  name="new_team">
        //etc etc i removed all the fields just to make it look simple
        <input type="submit" value="Save" name="new_team">
    </form>
```

And this is what the controller looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['new_team']))
{
  echo "echo here";
}
else {
 echo "echo there";
}
```

The **result** was **"echo there"**.
What is wrong? Could it be a WAMP config issue?

Comment: Check if it works by setting csrf_protection to false in config.php

Comment: @JubayerArefin it was already set to false   




 

$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;

Comment: I think remove name attribute from your form element might work. Because you repeated it twice.

Comment: try to print out $_POST and check you getting other input fields with new_team too. and also follow Indrasinh Bihola's comment.

Comment: change your form name or input field name as both are same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the whole WAMP server and then installed XAMPP server and imported everything from it. Then it started working. There was something wrong with the configuration. Anyway thanks everyone for the help :-)

Comment: You should accept your own answer since this resolved your issue.  Marking an accepted answer signifies to the system and researchers that this question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Repair syntax

```
if(isset($_POST['new_team']))
{
  echo "echo here";
}
else {
 echo "echo there";
}
```

Comment: Its not about braces. There's something wrong with the configuration of codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried CI's input class?

```
$this->input->post('new_team');
```

I'd suggest you better use

```
$this->input->get_post('new_team');
```

this allows you to switch between GET and POST without rewriting code. First try get, then post..

Comment: No i haven't. Can u please write the full code?? (With some form input tags)